# Windows 10 2 audio inputs

Tags: windows-10

I need to have 2 audio inputs, one from the default microphone and one for my soundboard which is using VB virtual audio cable however don't know how to do this

My beautiful graphic:

```
Soundboard -> VB virtual audio cable -> microphone input
                                        ^
(how do I do this?) My actual microphone^
```

Comment: What do you want to do with these 2 audio inputs? Evidently the intention is to mix the two, but for what purpose?

Comment: Input on a game. In this case cs:go